# Can any module be included into a large enough free module?

Tags: modules, injective-module

Can any module be included into a large enough free module?
For example if I'm looking at some R-module M, then would $\underset{m \in M}{\bigoplus} R$ containt M as an R-module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Every Abelian Group is a $\mathbb Z$-module, but a free $\mathbb Z$-module is torsion free (has no elements of finite order). So this fails, for example, for any finite abelian group as a $\mathbb Z$-module.